# Path Inheritance & Unified Path Variable Validation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am working on building an API which has the following structure:

```
/projects/{project-name}/a/...
/projects/{project-name}/b/...
/projects/{project-name}/c/...
/projects/{project-name}/d/...
```

I want the logic of a,b,c,d to be covered each on their own controller. Also, on each of these requests, I want to validate the {project-name} variable and inject an attribute on the request which will contain a project entity.

I definitely want to avoid checking the project on every controller.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this ? As far as I know, path inheritance is impossible on Spring Boot (I would really like to have the inheritance offered by other frameworks like RESTEasy for example).

The only thought I've made until now is the usage of a filter, but I would prefer a solution on the MVC/Webflux level.

I am using Spring Boot 3.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: (a) Sure filter is an option, which you have already considered (b) If all you need through separate controller classes is "separation of concern", then consider having just one endpoint as `/projects/{project-name}/{actual-end-point}/` on a method, which then can call an interface implementation based on the value of `end-point`.

Comment: @SreeKumar My problem is that if I do it that way, I lose the MVC management on the levels after /{actual-end-point}. I will not be able to easily extract request bodies, params etc. There are going to be at least 3-4 more levels after {actual-end-point}.

Comment: OK. I have another approach that needs some detailing. I will write an answer for that. You can check that out.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach

1. Write a base interface that is annotated with `@RequestMapping` with the desired base path.
2. Write implementations annotated with `@Controller`, but without `@RequestMapping` (so that the base path doesn't get overridden)
3. For the validation, use the filter approach itself.

[image]

**BaseController interface**

```java
@RequestMapping( "/projects/{project-id}" )
public interface BaseController {
}
```

**Sample child controller**

(You can write any number, as long as the final paths on the methods don't duplicate.)

```java
@Controller
public class ChildController implements BaseController{
    /* Add your controller method with the rest of the path */
    @RequestMapping( "/a/{id}" )
    public ResponseEntity<String> a( @PathVariable( "project-id" ) String projectId, @PathVariable( "id" ) String id ){
        /* You will get the path variable 'project-id' also */
        System.out.println( "/a: Path param project-id: " + projectId + ", Path param id: " + id );
        return ResponseEntity.ok( "Returned from /a" );
    }

    /* Add another controller method if you need to */
    @RequestMapping( "/b" )
    public ResponseEntity<String> b(){
        System.out.println( "/b" );
        return ResponseEntity.ok( "Returned from /b" );
    }
}
```

**Note:** The above code was tested with Java 11 and SpringBoot 2.7.4, which uses Spring MVC 5.2.x, I think.

---

### Validation of `project-id` using `@ModelAttribute`

(Based on an answer to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088179/spring-controllers-can-i-call-a-method-before-each-requestmapping-method-is-ca))

If we don't want to use a filter (though I will go for that anytime), we can add a method in the base interface with an `@ModelAttribute` annotation, which will be called before each end-point method. Though the documentation of `@ModelAttribute` isn't clear about it, it is being called anyhow. We can make the following change in `BaseController` for this approach.

```java
@RequestMapping( "/projects/{project-id}" )
public interface BaseController {
    @ModelAttribute
    default void interceptMVCMethod( HttpServletRequest req, @PathVariable( "project-id" ) String projectId ){
        System.out.println( "ModelAttribute: " + projectId );
        req.setAttribute( "NAME", "DEV-1" );
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach does not include the "centralized" validation of the {project-id} attribute and the injection of the project entity on each controller/method in controllers. That's the main issue.

Comment: About the validation of the `project-id`, I have mentioned using filters itself, like you had already thought of. That way, you can even add the request attribute based on the value.  If that doesn't help, then something innovative needs to be worked out for that!

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088179/spring-controllers-can-i-call-a-method-before-each-requestmapping-method-is-ca, I found that a method having `@ModelAttribute` on it is called for each end-point method. However, I advise that you go through the JavaDocs for `@ModelAttribute` before deciding to use it. (I will be editing my answer with the change anyhow.)